# increase exchange 2003 size of database

Tags: database, exchange-2003

how do i increase the size of my exchange database this morning in logged in and the first storage group had been dismounted so i mounted it again with no problems. I went to check event Viewver and i got this message

> Blockquote Exchange store 'First Storage Group\Mailbox Store (LONDON)': The current physical size of this database (the .edb file and the .stm file) is 31 GB. This database has exceeded the size limit of 30 GB. However, the logical free space in this database has not yet been evaluated. Therefore, it is possible that this database contains enough free space to bring its logical size below the maximum size limit.

How do i go about increasing the size of the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `Database Size Limit in GB` regkey which can be set in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSExchangeIS\<SERVER NAME>\Private-<GUID>`.

See the [relevant Exchange documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998066%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx) for details.